# Why GUI freezes when web browser navigates and loads?

Tags: c#, user-interface

How do I prevent GUI from freezing when a web browser navigates and loads the page?

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.costco.com/");
```

For example, when it navigates to that site, my program slightly freezes, especially when the web page is loading. I could not drag and move the form.  The tab buttons in the tab control can't be clicked. I have to wait for the web page to completely load for it to unfreeze.

I noticed that the Standalone Internet Explorer web browser does not behave that way. It does not freeze when the web page is loading.

How can I prevent the UI from freezing when a webpage is loading?

Comment: When are you calling `Navigate`, in what point in code?

Comment: under the button1_click

Comment: Have you tried using `async/await`?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience the Navigate method is a non blocking function and it won't freez UI.

one possible reason is that you call it before UI initialization ... you have to call this function after form is loaded :

```
bool form_loaded=false;

private void Navigate(String url)
{
if(form_laded)
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        form_loaded = true
}
.
.
.
void boo() 
{
   Navigate ( "http://stackoverflow.com" );
}
```

`

If you want to make sure UI is not freezing during navigating you can call `DoEvents` in every `OnProgressChanged` event :

```
private void webBrowser1_OnProgressChanged(WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents(); //update ui
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work. I tested your code by adding another tab control with two tab pages. When boo() gets executed, I rapidly mouse clicked tabpage1 and tabpage 2 multiple times and they cannot be clicked for about 1 to 2 seconds because the GUI slightly freezes during navigation when the web page is loading.

Comment: I think the problem is with webpage you are loading . Does it loads any plugin like java or flash-player ? ( They may cause problems like this)

Comment: Using `OnProgressChanged` is not helping. The freeze occurs especially when the page is waiting from quite heavy Ajax request.